# SQL Server managed backup to Azure fails with Subsystem 'SmartAdmin' could not be loaded

Tags: sql-server

I've been through all the steps to Enable SQL Server managed backup to Azure, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/enable-sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=azure-cli).
After some time of waiting, I noticed that no backup files are being saved to the storage location.

After a lot of digging and searching, I finally came across this entry in the SQL Server Agent Error Logs:

> Subsystem 'SmartAdmin' could not be loaded (reason: smartadmin
> subsystem is not available in loaded list of currently loaded
> subsystems)

A search for this error returns no results...can I really be the first person logging a query about this on the web?!?

Anyway, might be useful to note that I'm trying to set this up on a SQL Server instance that is running as a Docker Container on a Linux Server.

Any ideas as to how I get this SmartAdmin subsystem set up?